# Exploring mathematical relationship bewteen time-series of three variables and their ratios

Tags: functions, numerical-methods, physics, graphing-functions

I am trying to evaluate three parameters ($V_{1}$, $V_{2}$, and $V_{3}$) [(3D of V1 V2 and V3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Irr5y.jpg) related to a physical phenomenon and trying to find a mathematical connection between them. Time-series of these variables are measured. These parameters form a closed looped pattern when plotted [(Scatter plot of the time-series of three variables)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POBLV.png). Ratio of these variables can be defined as $R_{1}=\frac{V_{2}}{V_{1}}$,  $R_{2}=\frac{V_{2}}{V_{3}}$, $R_{3}=\frac{V_{1}}{V_{3}}$, $R_{4}=\frac{V_{1}}{V_{2}} = \frac{1}{R_{1}}$, $R_{5}=\frac{V_{3}}{V_{1}} = \frac{1}{R_{3}}$, and $R_{6}=\frac{V_{3}}{V_{2}} = \frac{1}{R_{2}}$. The times-series of these ratios is being calculated as defined. The physical system continues in a cycle and has six states. The plot of Variables (V1, V2, and V3) shows that they (mostly) interplay with each other concerning the state of the system. Moreover, these form a closed loop pattern. However, the ratios $R_{1}$, $R_{2}$, ... , $R_{6}$ have a very defined pattern [(Scatter plot of Ratios)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uh8fB.png); though, for any specific data point, it is not possible to tell that at which state of the system the ratio belongs. So far, so good, beyond that, I am unable to find a way to go further to explore these relationships. I am not sure how to explain the data and plot mathematically. What tools /methods should I use to develop (or explain) the mathematical relationship between these variables.

Comment: I suspect you are wasting time with extraneous dependent variables like $R_4,R_5,R_6$. You want to eliminate such. It appears that $R_2+R_3=$constant, and if this were so, then $V_1+V_2=c V_3$, so you could eliminate $V_3$ as well. In that case, you'd have a fancy periodic closed curve connecting $V_1$ with $V_2$.

Comment: To rephrase the implicit question: Can you establish a linear combination of $V_1,V_2,V_3$ which stays constant through the approximate cycle?

Comment: @CosmasZachos you are right,  theoretically it should be $V_1+V_2=c V_3$ with $c=1$. To further clarify the dataset, let me explain it is a bit. The three variables are recorded flows at an insection of two stream channels very close to a coastal area, experiencing water level variations due to tides.  To make sense of the [dataset](https://github.com/datakeen/VariablesnRatios/blob/master/Varaibales%20and%20Ratios.csv), I have made a [schematic illustration](https://github.com/datakeen/VariablesnRatios/blob/master/Stream%20Illustration.png) of the system.

Comment: I am mainly interested in mathematically resolving the looped relationship between $V_1$ and $V_2$ or $V_3$. In addition based on this mathematical relationship, I want to interpret (or link) the physical features of channels 1 and 2. So that the findings may be more generalized and not just related to the particular setup I am studying. I hope the question and its background are more refined now.